# Replace only the integers in a string with gsub

Tags: regex, ruby, gsub

Im trying to get rid of the integers in this string, but mantain the floats. I have tried the regex below online and highlights the right parts, but noting happens whe I use gsub

```
tops = "17500 dw.sapAGZ_D00 pf=/usr/sap/A  8.0 17488 dw.sapAGZ_D00 pf=/usr/sap/A  7.1 17489 dw.sapAGZ_D00 pf=/usr/sap/A  7.0 17493 dw.sapAGZ_D00 pf=/usr/sap/A  5.9 17490 dw.sapAGZ_D00 pf=/usr/sap/A  5.7 17495 dw.sapAGZ_D00 pf=/usr/sap/A  5.4 17499 dw.sapAGZ_D00 pf=/usr/sap/A  5.0 17480 dw.sapAGZ_D00 pf=/usr/sap/A  4.3 17492 dw.sapAGZ_D00 pf=/usr/sap/A  4.0"

tops.gsub(/(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|$)/, '--- ')

puts tops ;
```

Comment: you could try `gsub!` which performs the substitutions of `String#gsub` in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your search pattern is good (for the particular input - for example, it won't process negative integers properly I guess), but `gsub` just doesn't change the receiver (original string) - it returns a new one with all the substitutions.

So either use `gsub!` or reassign the string to another variable if you need the original one too.